# Segfault in g_tree_lookup

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I keep getting segfault in `g_tree_lookup()` function.

This line gives me an exception:

```
value = g_tree_lookup(tree, (gpointer *)triP);
```

`triP`, `tree` and `value` seem to be right. Here backtrace

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00002aaaaac10800 in ?? () from /opt/gnome/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00002aaaaac10def in g_tree_lookup () from /opt/gnome/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00000000004031ca in processXML (start=0x506011 "<I k=\"2723195,361,333\" b=\"908\""..., stop=0x51e6d6 "\n<I k=\"472672,847,814\" b=\"2216"..., tree=0x51e6c0) at c2.c:404
#3  0x000000000040375e in main () at c2.c:538
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x00000000004031ca in processXML (start=0x506011 "<I k=\"2723195,361,333\" b=\"908\""..., stop=0x51e6d6 "\n<I k=\"472672,847,814\" b=\"2216"..., tree=0x51e6c0) at c2.c:404
404       if( p != NULL  && (triP!=NULL) &&( (value = g_tree_lookup(tree, (gpointer *)triP) )!= NULL)  )
(gdb) print tree
$17 = (GTree *) 0x51e6c0
(gdb) print triP
$18 = 0x5ad1f0 "2723195,361,333"
(gdb) print value
$19 = (gpointer *) 0x40331e
```

I insert keys like this:

```
  const char *tri = OCI_GetString (rs,  1);
  printf("%s " , tri);
  g_tree_insert(tree,(gpointer *) g_strdup(tri), t);
```

Tree is created like this:

```
typedef struct tic {
  int         qotId;
  int         excId;
  char        closeTs[19];
  char        closeSixCode[10];
  double      close;
  double      open;
  double      high;
  double      low;
  double      volume;
  double      tradeVolume;
  double      turnover;
  double      ask;
  char        askTs[19];
  double      askVolume;
  double      bid;
  char        bidTs[19];
  double      bidVolume;
  float       realClose;
  char        realCloseTs[19];
  double      kassa;
  double      settle;
  char        settleTs[19];
  char        zusatz;
  double      anzahlTicHeute;
  double      midPrice;
  char        midPriceTs[19];
  char        supXpressfeed[32];
  char        source;
  char        tradeType[1];
  char        buyer;
}tic, *ticP;




int buildQotHash(GTree* tree, char (*str)[3000])
{
    OCI_Connection* cn;
    OCI_Statement* st;
    OCI_Resultset* rs;
    if (!OCI_Initialize(err_handler, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate( "db", "user",  "pass", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
    st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);
    char query[5000];
                                                                                      ");
    // CUT QUERY
    OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, query);
    rs = OCI_GetResultset(st);
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    while (OCI_FetchNext(rs))
    {

      tic *t         = malloc(sizeof(tic))  ;

      t->qotId           = OCI_GetInt    (rs,  2);
      t->close           = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  3);
      if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 4) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 4), DATEFORMAT, 19, t->closeTs );
      //t->closeTs         = OCI_GetString (rs,  4);
      t->open            = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  5);
      t->high            = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  6);
      t->low             = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  7);
      t->volume          = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  8);
      t->ask             = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  9);
      if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 10) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 10), DATEFORMAT, 19, t->askTs );
      t->askVolume       = OCI_GetFloat  (rs, 11);
      t->bid             = OCI_GetFloat  (rs, 12);
      if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 13) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 13), DATEFORMAT, 19, t->bidTs );
      t->bidVolume       = OCI_GetFloat  (rs, 14);
      t->realClose       = OCI_GetFloat  (rs, 15);
      if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 16) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 16), DATEFORMAT, 19, t->realCloseTs );
      //t->realCloseTs     = OCI_GetString (rs, 16);
      t->settle          = OCI_GetFloat  (rs, 17);
      if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 18) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 18), DATEFORMAT, 19, t->settleTs );
      strcpy(t->tradeType,  "H");
      strcpy(t->closeSixCode,  OCI_GetString  (rs,  19));
      const char *tri = OCI_GetString (rs,  1);
      printf("%s " , tri);
      g_tree_insert(tree,(gpointer *) g_strdup(tri), t);
      sprintf(str[j]+strlen(str[j]),"&ik%d=%s", i, tri);
      //i= (i > 99) ? i++ : 0;
      i > 99 ? j++ : j;
      i++;
      if(i > 100) i = 1;
    }

    OCI_Cleanup();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Hmm, I dont think so... Anyhow I can make a test.

Comment: Tree is initialized at the very beginning. I will check it once again when it happens, but it was usually ok.

Comment: What does the stack trace from the segfault look like (it might point you to what's corrupted, and if you're lucky who is responsible).

Comment: I'll send the whole stack when it happens again.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument (the key) looks fishy; are you sure it should be "pointer to pointer", i.e. `gpointer *`?

Note the prototype [from the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#g-tree-lookup):

```
gpointer g_tree_lookup(GTree *tree, gconstpointer key);
```

The second argument should just be a constant pointer, so the cast looks very suspicious.

You need to show more code to make sure, though.

Comment: the cast is suspicious (maybe a warning while compiling?), but he printed triP in gdb and it seems to point to a string, which is good as key, so it should be ok

Comment: No, I don't get any warning while compiling. This cast is ok.

Comment: @MaMu If `triP` is just a string pointer, the cast is totally wrong and should be removed, regardless of whether you get a warning.

Comment: `triP` is a pointer to const char. I have added more code. If you don't mind, please correct me how I should do the cast.

Comment: @MaMu Then your cast is clearly wrong. The additional code you posted also contains a broken cast, the return value of `g_strdup()` should not be cast when used as the key in `g_tree_insert()`. You need to show (still) more code, like how your tree is created.

Comment: I have added full tree generation. Could someone have a look, please?